# Definite integral with ln and more

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\int_1^e \frac{(\frac{1}{x})x - \ln x}{x^2} dx$$

Generally I don't like not contributing much to the problem but I'm slightly confused as to where to go here. I know that the numerator can be written as $1 - \ln x$ but what can I really do from this point? The only other thing I notice here(as I was hinted to) is that $$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right) = \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2} $$

but i'm not sure if this even helps.

Comment: Since you have the antiderivative, what is stopping you from evaluating its difference at the upper and lower limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand can be written as
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{\ln x}{x^2}
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

**Hint:** Integration by parts will be useful for the second term.

---

The above is a direct way to obtain the solution; however, if you must use the hint provided you can simply apply the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). That is, from your hint we have $F(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x}$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is your integrand, so from the fundamental theorem we have 
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^ef(x)dx = F(e)-F(1) = \frac{1}{e} - 0 = \frac{1}{e} 
\end{align}

Comment: Haven't learned integration by parts in lectures(or assigned even) for some reason, but I solved it after learning it. Was initially hesitant because I didn't know how to approach the second part. Thanks

Comment: @user382540 In that case, please see the edit

Comment: Why not $u$-substitution?  $u=\ln x$?

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic rules:

$$1-\ln x=\ln e-\ln x=\ln\frac ex$$

Now, if we let $u=\frac ex$, we end up with

$$\int\frac{\ln\frac ex}{x^2}dx=-\frac1e\int\ln u\ du$$

which is either what I would mark as well known, or an integration by parts problem.  Note the product here is $1\times\ln u$.